# What is the LaTeX command for this symbol? Looks like \smile over a \frown

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

The symbol looks like this:

[image: symbol]

In context:

[image: context]

It occurs in the paper: "Linear type theory for asynchronous session types - S. J. Gay & V. T. Vasconcelos".

What command can I use to generate this symbol? I've tried `\overset{\smile}{\frown}` but it doesn't look quite right - the `\frown` comes out too big.

Comment: `$\asymp$` with `amsmath`.  Use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Perfect, thanks! That is an awesome tool, I will use it in future.